# how can i add an attribute onClick oto my links generated automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add an attribute onClick to my links generated automatically with jquery.

I select the parent div and then search if it has a link child, then add the attribute onClick.

It works on localhost but not on server
there is my code :

```
$('div.holder_notify_drop_data,li.holder_notify_drop_data').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children('a').hasClass('holder_notify_drop_link')) {
        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            var url = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            $(this).children('a').attr('onClick', "openFrame('" + url + "','yes')");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };)
};
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Smells like cross-domain requests. :)

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Do the same thing as you are already doing on line 3 of your code.

Comment: i have used event delegation but it not works on server

Comment: @Mohamed: No you are not. At least not in the code you have posted. You are iterating through a list of elements and attaching handlers to each of them. That is *not* the same as event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

IMPORTANT: Also put your code inside a document-ready function and I would suggest you to use jQuery click() function instead of the way you have done, but that's okay:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('div.holder_notify_drop_data,li.holder_notify_drop_data').each(function(){
if ($(this).children('a').hasClass('holder_notify_drop_link')){
$(this).on('click',function(e) {
var url = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
$(this).children('a').attr('onClick',"openFrame('"+url+"','yes')");
  e.preventDefault();
});
};
)};

});
```

Comment: @Mohamed Okay. Can you try replacing the click event with jQuery click() function and try it again? 
For example: $('#someId').click(function(){//code}); 
and nest that under document-ready

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/g248G/.

HTML:

```
<div class="holder_notify_drop_data">
    <a class="holder_notify_drop_link" 
       href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="holder_notify_drop_data">
        <a class="holder_notify_drop_link"
           href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function openFrame(URL, option) {
    window.open(URL);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.holder_notify_drop_data,li.holder_notify_drop_data').each(function() {
        $(this).children('a').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            if ($link.hasClass('holder_notify_drop_link')) {
                var URL = $link.attr('href');
                $link.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    openFrame(URL, 'yes');
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [jQuery.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that?

This will bind click function to all current and future elements of `a` in `holder_notify_drop_data` container.

```
$('.holder_notify_drop_data').on('click', 'a', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    openFrame($(this).prop('href'), 'yes');
});
```